# How to control the vertical alignment of a table column text

Tags: tables

I have a table looks like the table below. I want to move the text of the first column to be vertically aligned to the center. How to do that?

[image]

The script:

```
%README: this copy with comprehensive attack and defences description.

\documentclass[compsoc, conference, letterpaper, 10pt, times]{IEEEtran}
\ifCLASSOPTIONcompsoc
  % IEEE Computer Society needs nocompress option
  % requires cite.sty v4.0 or later (November 2003)
  \usepackage[nocompress]{cite}
\else
  % normal IEEE

  \usepackage{cite}
\fi
\ifCLASSINFOpdf
\else
\fi

\usepackage{colortbl}       
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\newcommand{\head}[1]{\textnormal{\textbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\normal}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{l}{#1}}
\usepackage{amssymb}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amssymb
\usepackage{pifont}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pifont
\newcommand{\cmark}{\ding{51}}%
\newcommand{\xmark}{\ding{55}}%
\newcommand*\rot{\rotatebox{90}}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{msc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand{\quotes}[1]{``#1''} %for qoutation marks

\DeclareRobustCommand*{\IEEEauthorrefmark}[1]{%
\raisebox{0pt}[0pt][0pt]{\textsuperscript{\footnotesize\ensuremath{#1}}}}

\begin{document}
\title{Test}

\section{Section Contains Footnote}
\maketitle

\begin{table}[bt!] 
\caption{Title}
\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!} {
\begin{tabular} {lccccc}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{c}{A} 
&&\multicolumn{3}{c}{B} \\   
\cmidrule(lr){3-5} 
\\
& &  AAA & BBB & CCC 
\\ \hline
\rowcolor[gray]{.9} 
Text1 & & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark \\
Text2 & & \xmark & \cmark & \xmark \\
\rowcolor[gray]{.9} 
Text3  & & \cmark & \xmark & \xmark \\
Text4  & & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
}%end resize box
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I am sure there is an official `multirow` way of doing it, but you can also simply change the `A` you wish to move to `\smash{\raisebox{-3ex}{A}}`.  By the way, your MWE needs to also load the `graphicx` package...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you among other packages load also `multirow`, you can exploit it in your case:

```
\documentclass[compsoc, conference, letterpaper, 10pt, times]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{pifont}
\newcommand{\cmark}{\ding{51}}%
\newcommand{\xmark}{\ding{55}}%
\usepackage{booktabs, multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ l *{45}{c} }
  \toprule
    &   \multicolumn{3}{c}{B} \\
  \cmidrule(lr){2-4}
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{-2}{*}[0.5ex]{A}}
    &   AAA & BBB & CCC \\
  \midrule
  Text1 &   \cmark & \cmark & \cmark \\
  Text2 &   \xmark & \cmark & \xmark \\
  Text3 &   \cmark & \xmark & \xmark \\
  Text4 &   \cmark & \cmark & \cmark \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can raise the column heading into place from the second row and completely remove any height/depth changes this may cause:

[image]

```
\documentclass[compsoc, conference, letterpaper, 10pt, times]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{booktabs,pifont}
\newcommand{\cmark}{\ding{51}}%
\newcommand{\xmark}{\ding{55}}%

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ l *{5}{c} }
  \toprule
  & & \multicolumn{3}{c}{B} \\
  \cmidrule(lr){3-5}
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\raisebox{.65\normalbaselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{A}}
    & & AAA & BBB & CCC \\
  \midrule
  Text1 & & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark \\
  Text2 & & \xmark & \cmark & \xmark \\
  Text3 & & \cmark & \xmark & \xmark \\
  Text4 & & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Note the use of all the [`booktabs`](//ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) rules (like `\toprule`, `\bottomrule`, ...) rather than a mixture of traditional (like `\hline`) and `booktabs` rules.

The choice of `.65\normalbaselineskip` is purely arbitrary - more than `.5\normalbaselineskip`, which would put you halfway up on a regular line within the `tabular`. The extra `.15\normalbaselineskip` is because of the width of `\cmidrule` and some additional whitespace added by the `booktabs` package to spread out content. Modify this to suit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Using `multirow` + a small adjustment (due to the padding of booktabs rules) solves the problem. Since you alternate rowcolours, I teplaced `color`with `xcolor`+ `table` option, to use the `\rowcolor`{oddrowcolor}{evenrowcolor}`scheme.`resizebox`isn't required here, and anyway it shouldn't be used with tables, as it gives inconsistent fonts sizing. Better play with the font size and/or`tabcolsep`.

```
\documentclass[compsoc, conference, letterpaper, 10pt, times]{IEEEtran}
\ifCLASSOPTIONcompsoc
  % IEEE Computer Society needs nocompress option
  % requires cite.sty v4.0 or later (November 2003)
  \usepackage[nocompress]{cite}
\else
  % normal IEEE

  \usepackage{cite}
\fi
\ifCLASSINFOpdf
\else
\fi

\usepackage[table, svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\newcommand{\head}[1]{\textnormal{\textbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\normal}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{l}{#1}}
\usepackage{amssymb}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amssymb
\usepackage{pifont}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pifont
\newcommand{\cmark}{\ding{51}}%
\newcommand{\xmark}{\ding{55}}%
\newcommand*\rot{\rotatebox{90}}
\usepackage{multirow, tabularx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{msc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand{\quotes}[1]{``#1''} %for quotation marks

\DeclareRobustCommand*{\IEEEauthorrefmark}[1]{%
\raisebox{0pt}[0pt][0pt]{\textsuperscript{\footnotesize\ensuremath{#1}}}}

\begin{document}

\title{Test}

\section{Section Contains Footnote}
\maketitle

\begin{table}[bt!]
\centering
\caption{Title}
\rowcolors{4}{}{Gainsboro}
\begin{tabular} {lccccc}
\toprule
\multirow{2}{*}[-0.6ex]{A}&&\multicolumn{3}{c}{B} \\
\cmidrule(lr){3-5}
& & AAA & BBB & CCC
\\ \hline
Text1 & & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark \\
Text2 & & \xmark & \cmark & \xmark \\
Text3 & & \cmark & \xmark & \xmark \\
Text4 & & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\lipsum[1-6]

\end{document}
```

[image]